# Why can't I make a loop to limited loop in python?

Tags: python, while-loop

I try to create a game room and I want it to ask for a room number, but I want it to ask untill player is max, if game room not max my code will ask again and again untill the game room is max.

This is my code:

```
# 1. Enter C for create game room (DONE)
# 2. Enter how many player? (DONE)
# 3. Create game room (DONE)
# 4. Get room number (DONE)
# 5. Enter room number for join (X)
# 6. When player is max, ask for ready to play or not? (X)
# 7. Enter R for ready, N for not (X)
# 8. If everyone is ready, player 1 enter P for play (X)
# 9. Enjoy the game! (X)

def roomnum_join():
    import random as rd            ### Random function for random room number
    return rd.randint(1,10)        ### Return Value for use it later.. (for second time or rather than)

def text_unsuccess():
    print("Don't enter letters or let it blank.")
    print('Please enter number rather than 0.') 

def notfound_roomnum():
    print('Room number not found.')
    print('Please enter correct room number (6-digits).')

len_success = 'Created Successfully!.'

create = ''

while create != 'C':
    create = input('Enter C for create: ')
    if create == 'C':
        print('How many player in game room?')
        while True:
            try:
                player = int(input('Enter player: '))
            except ValueError:                                      # ]
                print('\nCreated Unsuccesfully.')                   # ] >> Unsuccess
                text_unsuccess()                                    # ]
                continue

            if player <= 0:                                          # ]
                print('\nCreated Unsuccesfully.')                    # ] >> Unsuccess
                text_unsuccess()                                     # ] 
            else:
                i = 1
                amount_player = f'Waiting for the other player.. {i}/{player}.'
                roomnum = roomnum_join()
                print('='*len(amount_player))                             
                print('Created Successfully!.')                          # ]
                print(f'Your room number is {roomnum}.')                 # ] >> Success 
                print(f'Waiting for the other player.. {i}/{player}.')   # ]
                print('='*len(amount_player))  
                break

while True:
    try:
        enter_roomnum = int(input('\nEnter room number for join: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('\nJoined Unsuccesfully.')
        notfound_roomnum()
        continue
    else:
        if enter_roomnum != roomnum:
            notfound_roomnum()
        elif enter_roomnum == roomnum:
            i += 1
            print('='*len(amount_player)) 
            print(f'You join room number {roomnum}.')
            print(f'Waiting for the other player.. {i}/{player}.')
            print('='*len(amount_player))
```

This is my output:

```
Enter C for create: C
How many player in game room?
Enter player: 4
===================================
Created Successfully!.
Your room number is 7.
Waiting for the other player.. 1/4.
===================================

Enter room number for join: 7
===================================
You join room number 7.
Waiting for the other player.. 2/4.
===================================

Enter room number for join: 7
===================================
You join room number 7.
Waiting for the other player.. 3/4.
===================================

Enter room number for join: 4
Room number not found.
Please enter correct room number (6-digits).

Enter room number for join: 3
Room number not found.
Please enter correct room number (6-digits).

Enter room number for join: 7
===================================
You join room number 7.
Waiting for the other player.. 4/4.
===================================

Enter room number for join: 7
===================================
You join room number 7.
Waiting for the other player.. 5/4.
===================================

Enter room number for join:
```

As you see, I want it to ask untill player is max such as 1/4..2/4..3/4..4/4 and finish to next step, but now I can't do it. I wonder, do I have to use for-lopp or some thing else?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop asking for the room number once the maximum number of players has been reached, you can add a condition to your second while loop that checks if the current number of players i is equal to the maximum number of players player. If this condition is true, you can break out of the while loop and move on to the next step. Please refer below:

```
while True:
if i == player:
    print("The game room is full!")
    break
try:
    enter_roomnum = int(input('\nEnter room number for join: '))
except ValueError:
    print('\nJoined Unsuccesfully.')
    notfound_roomnum()
    continue
else:
    if enter_roomnum != roomnum:
        notfound_roomnum()
    elif enter_roomnum == roomnum:
        i += 1
        print('='*len(amount_player)) 
        print(f'You join room number {roomnum}.')
        print(f'Waiting for the other player.. {i}/{player}.')
        print('='*len(amount_player))
```

with the above changes, once the maximum number of players have joined the game room, the program will stop asking for the room number and move on to the next step.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your second while loop.

You'd want to stop asking for more players after the `player` matches `i`

I don't know if you just want to break out of the while loop or return something.

So on your second while(True):

```
while(True):
  if i == player:
     break #i matches the max number of players
  try:
    ...
  except:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix to this is you have to check whether the joined players are equal to the max number of players, in this case **i** is the players joining, and **player** is the total number of players.

Just update your last while loop to this:

```
while True:
    try:
        enter_roomnum = int(input('\nEnter room number for join: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('\nJoined Unsuccesfully.')
        notfound_roomnum()
        continue
    if i == player:
        print('All player is ready to play.')
        break
    if enter_roomnum != roomnum:
        notfound_roomnum()
    elif enter_roomnum == roomnum:
        i += 1
        print('='*len(amount_player)) 
        print(f'You join room number {roomnum}.')
        print(f'Waiting for the other player.. {i}/{player}.')
        print('='*len(amount_player))
```